# Possible to create custom folding area in Java file?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA automatically creates folding area only for methods and classes (and other similar things). Is it possible to create a custom folding area so that I could fold/unfold logical area?

For example, there is a Java file which contains 5 methods which get/save data into the `SharedPreferences`. I want to fold this whole region together, not each method one by one.

```
//fold this area from here...
public void method1()
{
...
}

public void method2(args)
{
...
}

public void method3(args, args)
{
...
}
//...to here!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight it and go <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Alternatively, you can right click, select folding, and select "Fold Selection".

Comment: Will it create a +/- for later folding? Or this is just ad-hoc folding?

Comment: @bergnam Yes, it does. The same key combination can be used to remove the new folding region.